# How to get a UWP DataTemplate to use the sizing of it's ListView?

Tags: xaml, uwp

In the example below, the ListView control understands the width of it's parent container RelativePanel.  When looking a the layout in the designer, it is clear that the ListView is filling out to the full width of the RelativePanel.  However, even though the RelativePanel inside the DataTemplate is also asking to fill out the width of the parent, it ignores the "align left" and "align right".  I can't seem to find any way to get it to recognize it's parent container's size.

Any suggestions here would be appreciated.

```
            <RelativePanel RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                          RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">
                <ListView Name="LstOrders" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Vm.OrdersList, Mode=OneWay}" 
                          SelectionMode="None"
                          RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                          RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                          Margin="0,5,0,0">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="genericOrder:OrderThumbnailVm">
                            <RelativePanel Name="PanelThumbnail" Margin="0,0,20,0">
                                <RelativePanel Name="PanelOrderDetails" 
                                               Background="BlueViolet"
                                               RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                               RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" Margin="8,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                               Foreground="{x:Bind Deleted, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource DeletedColor}}"
                                               TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                                               RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                               RelativePanel.LeftOf="BtnDeleteRestore"/>
                                    <Button Name="BtnDeleteRestore" 
                                            Content="{x:Bind DisplayDelete, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                            Click="{x:Bind DeleteOrder}"
                                            RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                                            FontSize="10"
                                            Height="20"
                                            Padding="0"
                                            Visibility="{x:Bind ShowDeleteButton, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                                </RelativePanel>
                            </RelativePanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </RelativePanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the value of `HorizontalContentAlignment`of `ListViewItem` is `Left`, we need to override it and make it `Stretch`. You can find it in the [ListViewItem styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx).

To solve this problem, as I said, we need to override its style, for example like this:

```
<ListView>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <RelativePanel>
                  ...
                </RelativePanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Works like a charm! I have been trying just about everything, except trying to set the container style.