# Fluid Layouts in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am trying to position a button in a list view on the far right of the screen with no luck.

I have this so far,

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="local:SSS">
                    <RelativePanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="A"
                            Text="{x:Bind xxx}" 
                            FontWeight="Bold"
                            RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                            RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
                            RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"/>
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="B"
                            Text="{x:Bind xxx}" 
                            TextAlignment="Right"
                            RelativePanel.RightOf="A"
                            RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                            RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
                            RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"/>
                    </RelativePanel>                     
                </DataTemplate>
```

How can I push the second text block to the far right of the screen ?

```
|A                               B|
```

Comment: The issue may be the listview.  you need to tell it to use full width. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438106/how-to-get-a-uwp-datatemplate-to-use-the-sizing-of-its-listview

Comment: @MarkW That worked ! If you could put that as an answer I will accept it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue with the listview.  You need to coerce the items to take up the full width in they styling.  Please see linked post...

[Link to answer by Grace Feng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438106/how-to-get-a-uwp-datatemplate-to-use-the-sizing-of-its-listview)

The bit you need:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```